# Best way to integrate webpack builds with ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, webpack, msbuild, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm upgrading my ASP.NET Core app to V3, and using Visual Studio 2019 for development / debugging. The process has been smooth except for this:

```
public void Configure(…..
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = false,
                    ReactHotModuleReplacement = false
                });
```

UseWebpackDevMiddleware is no more: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12890 .

I'm now looking to understand the best way to have VS run webpack every time I debug, ideally only on JS code that has changed. This was the value I was getting from `UseWebpackDevMiddleware`. My app is a React app, and it seems like there is some new replacement for this if your app was started from CreateReactApp, but mine was not.  (I believe apps that stated from this but then separated are called "ejected.") Is it somehow possible for me to still take advantage of whatever that facility is, even though my app does not leverage CreateReactApp? Also, what is the role of CreateReactApp after it bootstraps your new React application? I imagined it would be only used for inflating template code at the first go.

What is the role of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions in all of this?

I don't need hot module replacement; I don't need server side prerendering. I'm really just trying to understand how to get my JS to transparently build (via Webpack) as part of my debugging process. Is this something that I could hook into MSBuild for? I imagine others are going to face the same question as they upgrade.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*You mention VS. My solution is good for Visual Studio, but not VS Code.*

I use WebPack Task Runner: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner

This adds webpack.config.js tasks into the "Task Runner Explorer" in Visual Studio, and you can then bind those tasks to events like "Before Build" or "After Build"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But would editing a JavaScript (or, in my case, Typescript) file trigger a build in VS upon debugging?

Comment: Double clicking a task in Task Runner Explorer will launch it. So you could skip the binding to build, and then just double click on Watch - Development to start the `webpack is watching the files...` It will keep running.

Comment: This doesn't do the hot module replacement though, which is the main thing which `UseWebpackDevMiddleware` offers

Comment: @JamieF The link to the extension is broken as it includes the closing square bracket as part of the query parameter. This should work: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner)

Comment: "Watch - Development" on the Task Runner works perfectly

Comment: I ended up using the NPM task runner instead. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner It doesn't require webpack to be globally installed which is important because some projects may use a different version of webpack. This also allows you to have a custom set of scripts so you can perform certain steps before the watch.

Answer (score 33):

So, I was using `UseWebpackDevMiddleware` for HMR for a much smoother dev process - In the end I reverted to using `webpack-dev-server`

Steps:

1) Add package to package.json: `"webpack-dev-server": "3.8.2",`
2) Add `webpack.development.js`

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.config.js');
const ExtractCssPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const webpackDevServerPort = 8083;
const proxyTarget = "http://localhost:8492";

module.exports = merge(common(), {
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        proxy: {
            '*': {
                target: proxyTarget
            }
        },
        port: webpackDevServerPort
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractCssPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ]
});
```

**Note that the proxy setting here will be used to proxy through to ASP.Net core for API calls**

Modify `launchSettings.json` to point to webpack-dev-server:

```
"profiles": {
    "VisualStudio: Connect to HotDev proxy": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:8083/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8492/"
    }
  }
```

(also I had some problem with configuring the right locations in webpack, and found [this](https://medium.com/code-oil/burning-questions-with-answers-to-why-webpack-dev-server-live-reload-does-not-work-6d6390277920)  useful

Also, will need to start webpack-dev-server which can be done via a npm script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:hotdev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.development.js --hot --inline",
```

And then this is bootstrapped

```
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "build:hotdev");
                }
            });
```

(or you can install the npm task runner extension and:

```
  "-vs-binding": {
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "build:hotdev"
    ]
  }
```

Alternatively I realise you can proxy the other way using the following - this way any request to under "dist" will be pushed through to the proxy `webpack-dev-server`

```
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "dist";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    // Ensure that you start webpack-dev-server - run "build:hotdev" npm script
                    // Also if you install the npm task runner extension then the webpack-dev-server script will run when the solution loads
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:8083");
                }
            });
```

And then you don't need to proxy though from that back any more and can just serve /dist/ content 
 - both hot and vendor-precompiled using as web.config.js like this:

```
module.exports = merge(common(), {
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: '/dist/',
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        port: 8083,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname,"wwwroot"),
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractCssPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
    ]
});
```

Comment: This to me should have been the real answer since this allows you to retain HMR where as the task runner you have to manually trigger it.

Comment: Could you please explain, why we use "wwwroot" in contentBase, not "dist"?

Comment: `wwwroot` is the default "public" path for .NET applications.

Comment: UseSpa is no longer available in 3.1. asp.net core is not a stable platform, another breaking change.

Comment: This appears correct that UseSpa is gone as of 3.1 and 5.0 according to the documentation. @Kram, do you have any thoughts on a new approach that doesn't rely on this method? If so, would you be able to update your answer? Thanks...

Comment: Hano Johannes Rossouw:   Actually, Jamie's Solution is the much more concise one...  if you run "Watch - Development " on the Task Runner as he suggests: code changes are automatically transpiled same as HMR

Comment: Wayne, BenjiFB: Still exists in 3.1, moved to SpaServices.Extensions https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.5/src/Middleware/SpaServices.Extensions/src/SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs

Comment: Any GitHub repo for this?

Comment: I followed this steps but it is not working for me as expected. Here is the content of my project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516646/visual-studio-react-typescript-webpack-dev-server-hot-reload-not-working-for-com

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, Kram's answer should be marked as accepted as it really gives what's needed. I've spent some time setting up a .NET Core/React/Webpack project recently, and I could not get the `spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer` to work, but the `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` works like a charm. Thanks Kram!

Here are my few gotchas they might help someone:

webpack.config.js (excerpt):

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'build.[hash].js',
},

devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/dist',
    open: false,
    hot: true
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
]
```

1. DevServer sets its root by `publicPath` property and completely ignores the `output.path` property in the root. So even though your output files (for prod) will go to dist folder, under webpack server they will be served under a root by default. If you want to preserve the same url, you have to set `publicPath: '/dist'`.
   This means that your default page will be under http://localhost:8083/dist. I could not figure out a way to place assets under subfolder while keeping index in the root (other than hardcode the path for assets).
2. You need `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` in order to watch mode to work and also `hot: true` setting in the devServer configuration (or pass it as a parameter upon start).
3. If you (like me) copy some dev server configuration with `open: true` (default is false), you will finish up with two browsers opened upon application start as another one is opened by the launchSettings `"launchBrowser": true`. It was a bit of a surprise at the first moment.

Also, you will have to enable CORS for your project otherwise your backend calls will get blocked:

Startup.cs (excerpt):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => 
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: "developOrigins",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8083");
            });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseCors("developOrigins");
}
```

If anything else will come to my mind I will update the answer, hope this helps to someone.

**Webpack 5 update**

`webpack-dev-server` command doesn't work anymore. Use:

```
"build:hotdev": webpack serve --config webpack.config.development.js
```

You might also need to add `target: 'web'` to your `webpack.config.js` in Webpack 5 to enable hot module reload to work:

```
module.exports = {
    target: 'web'
}
```

Alternatively you might need to create a browserlist file. Hope this issue gets fixed soon.

Comment: hey man, so you just add `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` and I guess you added the option `hot` to your webpack script and Hot reload was working? I followed Kram's and add some of yours editing but i cannot make hot reload works. I still have to rebuild the solution everytime i do a change in css or js -.-

Comment: I do have `hot: true` in the devServer settings (I've edited my answer to add it there too). Then I have a an npm script `"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.development.js"` and I just start the server using `yarn start`.

Comment: thank you very much for your replay! 
I'm sure new in .Net so i feel very lost. I think my main problem is that in this project they use Razor pages. So i don't have a inde.html to generate for my dist/ folder. Or at least i didn't figured out how to do it yet. If you have any suggestion on how to work with webpack and razor.. is very welcome!

Comment: Webpack doesn't need razor pages, it supplies it's own index.html, you only need to tell .NET back-end where to look for the page. Try to look at some blogs, ie https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-webpack-in-asp-net-core-projects-a-basic-react-template-sample-25a3681a5fc2. That should give you more understanding about the whole concept.

Comment: thanks for the link!! Is so difficult to find documentation online about this, maybe your link will help me

Answer (score 2):

Extension is here : AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions

You could find examples here : https://github.com/RimuTec/AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions

With core 3.1 or 5.0
React with webpack

using :`spaBuilder.UseWebpackDevelopmentServer(npmScriptName: "start");`